# Unable to View Undelievered Mail in CF Administrator

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

When I go to the Mail option in CF10 and click the "View Undelivered Mail" button I am getting following errors:

> Error retrieving markup for element mailBody : Client verification
>   failure. [Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to your URL parameters
>   to see more information]
>
> Error invoking CFC /CFIDE/administrator/mail/undeliveredmail.cfc :
>   Client verification failure. [Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to
>   your URL parameters to see more information]

Does anyone have any idea why am I not able to see Undelivered mail?

Comment: FYI, updated to include main `[coldfusion]` tag for better question visibility.

Comment: Did you try adding `cfdebug` to your URL to see if you get any more information?  If so, please post info with your question.

Comment: I am not sure where to add cfdebug to url. Pardon me I am novice in coldfusion.

Comment: Are you able to see the directory listing on the server outside of CF admin to see what is there?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting any ColdFusion related cookies in your browser, such as `CFID`, `CFTOKEN`, `CFAUTHORIZATION_cfadmin` and `CFADMIN_LASTPAGE_ADMIN`, and then restart your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Look for an 0-byte file named something like "**Mail4117192657238440155.cfmail**" in your **/Applications/ColdFusion10/cfusion/Mail/Undelivr** folder and delete it. That fixed the problem for me.